# Using RxJava and Resuable Retrofit to create rest client - Observable

Tags: gson, observable, retrofit2, rx-java, okhttp

Am getting this error **tried to access method com.google.gson.Gson.newJsonWriter(Ljava/io/Writer;)Lcom/google/gson/stream/JsonWriter; from class retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonRequestBodyConverter** when trying to use Retrofit

```
compile('com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2')
    compile('com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.14.1')
    compile('com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.1')
    compile('com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0')
    compile('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0')
    compile('com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.5.0')
```

**My class implementation is as below**

```
public class RetrofitService {

    private static OkHttpClient getClient() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
                .addInterceptor(chain -> {
                    Request request = chain.request();
                    return chain.proceed(request
                            .newBuilder()
                            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                            .method(request.method(), request.body()).build());
                });
        return builder.build();
    }

    private static Gson getGson() {
        return new GsonBuilder()
                .create();
    }

    private static Retrofit getRestAdapter(String baseUrl) {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(getGson()))
                .client(getClient())
                .build();
    }

    static RepositoryInterface getService(String baseUrl) {
        return getRestAdapter(baseUrl).create(RepositoryInterface.class);
    }
}
```

Interface Implementations

```
public interface RepositoryInterface {
    
    @POST("user")
    Observable<Response<Void>> createUser(
            @Header("S-Key") String sKey,
            @Header("X-Id") String xId,
            @Body HashMap<String, String> body
    );

    @GET("user/{X-Id}")
    Observable<Response<ApiUser>> getUser(
            @Header("S-Key") String sKey,
            @Path("X-Id") String xId
    );
}
```

Where could i have gone wrong? Please help

Answer (score 0):

can you just try this line

```
.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
```

instead of

`.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(getGson()))`

while creating a retrofit object.

Edit: In case of dependency cycle for GSON sdk

```
configurations.all { 
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
}
```

also check the dependency tree using

```
./gradlew app:dependencies --configuration implementation
```

Comment: Still to gives me same error `failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.gson.Gson.newJsonWriter(Ljava/io/Writer;)Lcom/google/gson/stream/JsonWriter; from class retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonRequestBodyConverter] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.gson.Gson.newJsonWriter(Ljava/io/Writer;)Lcom/google/gson/stream/JsonWriter; from class retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonRequestBodyConverter
        at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonRequestBodyConverter.convert(GsonRequestBodyConverter.java:46)`

Comment: hmm it seems then gson is duplicated in some other libary as well with different version. you can either enforce the gson library to use single version.

Comment: added a edit for the issue have a look if it solves

Comment: It didn't work. Please check my complete [build.gradle](https://justpaste.it/1kha1) file and advice https://justpaste.it/edit/37308595/n17loglww6o17rap